# Is there a way to use my original .bib file with a new .sty format?

Tags: bibliographies

I apologize if I'm not asking this question correctly. Basically, I have a paper written in latex and I'm submitting it to a new journal. The journal has a specific style they want me to use, and provide a .sty file along with an example .tex file and .bst file. I'm using Overleaf, if that matters.

I just copied the packages at the top of their example .tex file to mine (and got rid of my old ones), but I'm having trouble with the bibliography.

In my original paper, I did the following. I used the package `\usepackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}`. I had a file, mybiblio.bib, with reference items in this format:

```
@inproceedings{lucchese2000filtering,
  title={Filtering Color Images in the xyY Color Space.},
  author={Lucchese, Luca and Mitra, Sanjit K},
  booktitle={ICIP},
  pages={500--503},
  year={2000}
}
```

In the text, I included a reference by doing `\cite{lucchese2000filtering}`, for example. To include the bibliography, I did:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybibliography.bib}
```

And it handled it all very nicely. The reference items in my .bib file were in an arbitrary order, but it listed the references at the end in the order they were cited.

Now, this new format seems to do it in a different way. In their reference section, the code they use is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{bib1}P. J. Harshman, T. K. Gustafson, and P. Kelley, ``Title of paper," J. Chem. Phys. {\bfseries 3}, (to be published).
\end{thebibliography}
```

And they have a .bst file that appears to be a bibliography style file.

My question is, how can I use my current .bib file to insert the references in this new format? I have ~50 references and thus really, really can't manually type them out in their new format.

Is there an easy solution I'm missing, especially using Overleaf?

Comment: Remove the `thebibliography` stuff and use `natbib` like you used to. Use their `bst` file by changing `bibliographystyle` accordingly. But i would ask the editors for advice as well, they know best what is needed.

Comment: Aside: You shouldn't include the extension `.bib` in the argument of `\bibliography`.

Comment: Please tell us (a) the name of the bibliography style file you are being asked to use and (b) what kind of citation call-outs are required by the publisher -- numeric, author-year, or something else?

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you for the advice. Now it appears to be giving me a compile error, Runaway argument?
]{elliot2007color,mehta2009blue,maier2008mediation,morrot2001color,ro\ETC.
Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete. I googled it but it seems like there are many possible causes... Do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: @Mico Ahh, thank you, I didn't know that. I've gotten rid of the .bib.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with some of the language here. By citation call-outs, I assume you mean the part that appears in the text when you want to cite? If so, it's just numeric, in order of appearance, which is what I was using anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, the only thing you should have to do is to replace the line

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{xxxx}
```

where xxxx is the name of their `.bst` file (without the `.bst`).

The `\begin{thebibliography}{99}...\end{thebibliography}` stuff is what you get after running `bibtex` in a `.bbl` file. Maybe they want you to include that in your main file instead of the `bibliography` line.

Comment: It's probably worth stating explicitly that after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, it is necessary to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes. (I'm confident that *you* know this; however, the OP may not be.) Moreover, depending on the citation callout style required by the journal, it may be necessary to load `natbib` with either the `numbers` or the `authoryear` option.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I changed it to what you said but it's still a little of and I'm confused. For example, in their template document (with the code in my OP), there's a horizontal line above and below the references, that I assume is automatically placed there or something. I'm not very familiar with these Latex reference programs... So if I'm using natbib, which seems to automatically choose and sort my references, do I have to use bibtex instead, to work with their system? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I read a thread here which explained to me that natbib *uses* bibtex, but I'm still a little confused. I don't have a .bbl file, I only have my one .bib file and the journal's .bst file. Do I need to produce that .bbl file or something? Thank you.

Comment: @YungHummmma - `natbib` does not use BibTeX, at least not directly. `natbib` is a LaTeX package; its code is used by LaTeX. At the end of a LaTeX run, various pieces of information are written to the `aux` file; among these are (a) the name of the bibliography style to the employed by BibTeX, (b) the name(s) of the `bib` file(s) containing the raw bibliographic entries, and (c) the keys of the entries that are to be cited in the body of the document and to be formatted and typeset in the bibliography. BibTeX uses these three pieces of information to create the `bbl` file. (... continued ...)

Comment: (cont'd) During the next run of LaTeX, when the `\bibliography` statement is encountered, LaTeX looks for the `.bbl` file and -- assuming it is found and can be read -- inserts the contents of the `.bbl` file into the input stream to be processed. LaTeX also reads and stores pieces of meta information about each bib item in the bbl file  and associates them with the `\cite` commands contained in the body of the document. During the *next* LaTeX run, the citation call-outs are completed. This is why a complete compile cycle involving bib items means running LaTeX-BiBTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX.